# output a file with a variable name in shell

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

So I am trying to output a file with the name of like: lastlogin-"yyyymmdd" where it contains the current date.
I figured out the date should be : `date +"%Y%m%d"`  and I tried to do a variable

`now = date +"lastlogin-%Y%m%d.txt"
 filename = ${now}
 xxxxx > ${filename}`
but nothing seems to work

Please help

Answer (score 4):

Use command substitution:

```
lastlogin-"$(date '+%Y%m%d')".txt
```

To save in a variable:

```
filename="lastlogin-"$(date '+%Y%m%d')".txt"
```

and then do:

```
echo 'foobar' >"$filename"
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `$()` for command execution and storage of result:

```
now=$(date +"lastlogin-%Y%m%d.txt")
```