# How to create a variable which contains text file name and timestamp in makefile?

Tags: shell, makefile

I'm trying use the make variable to store the name and timestamp so I can copy another files contents with a timestamped name. However, I keep receiving "FILENAME: Not found" and destination is missing for the cp command.

I've looked at the answers from but had no luck.
[output a file with a variable name in shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38665552/output-a-file-with-a-variable-name-in-shell)
There is a newline and tab before FILENAME and cp command but SO is not showing it.

```
initial:
    FILENAME = $(date +"file%F-%T.txt")
    cp backup/file.txt $$(FILENAME)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, I keep receiving "FILENAME: Not found" and destination is missing for the cp command.

Well that's not surprising.  Well, maybe a little surprising: I wouldn't expect make to even try to execute the `cp` command.

The recipe for each rule is expected to be a sequence of shell commands.  In particular, `make` will interpret this line as a shell command after expanding the `$(...)` part:

> ```
>     FILENAME = $(date +"file%F-%T.txt")
> ```

That's not correct shell syntax for setting a variable (the whitespace around the `=` is not allowed for that purpose) so it will try to execute a *command* named "FILENAME", which presumably it will not find in the path.  `make` should report an error there, and I would expect it to stop processing the recipe.

If it continued, however, then you have additional problems.  Doubling the `$$` in the next recipe line causes it to expand to a single `$`, so if the shell command that would be executed if that line were processed would be

```
cp backup/file.txt $(FILENAME)
```

But to the shell, the `$(...)` syntax executes *the command* inside the parentheses and expands to its standard output.  So *again*, this tries to execute a command `FILENAME`.

**What's more**, each line of the recipe is executed by a separate invocation of the shell, so shell variables set on one line of a recipe are not available on other lines, which run in different shells.

If you only want the timestamp for one recipe, then I'd recommend skipping the variable altogether:

```
initial:
    cp backup/file.txt "$$(date +'file%F-%T.txt')"
```

If you want to store it for re-use, *and* you're using and willing to depend on GNU's implementation of `make`, then you can instead store the timestamp in a `make` variable, which you must do outside any rule:

```
TIMESTAMP = $(shell date +'file%F-%T.txt')
```

And then let `make` expand it instead of relying on the shell to do so:

```
initial:
    cp backup/file.txt "$(TIMESTAMP)"
```